# Sending POST requests using Cookies

Tags: c#, post, cookies, authentication, webrequest

I want to send a POST request via WebRequest using the following POST:

```
POST https://olui2.fs.ml.com/ClientFederation/LoginValidateUser.asmx/ValidatePassword HTTP/1.1
Host: olui2.fs.ml.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 76
Origin: https://olui2.fs.ml.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
__PageIdHeader: jclrKnUbxSsmkPo01YGJFc4O9l3kt79RUdjpUT9mB3E=
X-Bear: jclrKnUbxSsmkPo01YGJFc4O9l3kt79RUdjpUT9mB3E=
Accept: */*
Referer: https://olui2.fs.ml.com/login/ConfirmIdentity.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: pxv=da927b45-fda7-440d-893e-5058b60053b1; __g_u=277817800941577_1_1_1_5_1422571043310_1; __g_c=a%3A0; pxss=392613e3-6d74-4947-b707-8b6ce7a1df8e; FSDSession=true; Bear=jclrKnUbxSsmkPo01YGJFc4O9l3kt79RUdjpUT9mB3E=; NSC_pmvj2-NzNfssjmm-wt=9fea903a0000; pxsq=19

{"username":"username","rememberMe":false,"password":"mypassword","data":null}
```

The {} is for the JSON. Here's the code I have so far:

```
        //Get the variables
        string url = "http://olui.fs.ml.com/Login/Login.aspx";
        string userName = loginUN;
        string userPassword = loginPW;

        //Connection Parameters
        string method = "POST";

        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://olui2.fs.ml.com/ClientFederation/LoginValidateUser.asmx/ValidatePassword");
        webReq.Connection = "keep-alive";
        webReq.ContentLength = 76;
        webReq.UserAgent = " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36";
        webReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        webReq.Accept = "*/*";
        webReq.Referer = " https://olui2.fs.ml.com/login/ConfirmIdentity.aspx";
```

I'm not sure how to set the cookie I need to use to login. Secondly, there are a few parts of the request I can't find in my `WebRequest`, i. e. Accept-Language, Cache-Control, X-Request and all parts south.

Another big thing I'm not sure about is the JSON of the username and password.

Comment: Trying to programmatically log into the Bank of America website is, at best, a terrible idea and, at worst, sounds more than a little suspicious.

Comment: I'm just trying to automate the process for a client. I have been using Selenium via Java but was looking for a faster process without all the logging. No malicious intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple challenges in a single question. Maybe better split your set of problems into multiple questions.

Anyway, I focus here on your firstly mentioned cookie challenge. The `HttpWebRequest` component has a `CookieContainer` property. You need to create an instance of the cookie container and attach it to that particular property. Example:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = ...
webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webReq.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("name", "value", "/", yourDomain));
// etc.
```

Here's a nice blog that may help even further: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2004/08/24/219714.aspx

Comment: That's gonna help a ton! You, sir, are a noble man! I'll split up the question into the parts not answered and prepare for the backlash once more.